# Sync after creating buildSrc doesn't do anything

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am converting my project to Kotlin DSL and I would also like to use buildSrc folder. According to tutorials the first step is to create buildSrc directory in the project root (same level as app directory), hit "sync project with gradle files" and it should automatically create some more folders and files inside of it and make it a "module". However in my case it doesn't do anything. Can anyone help me?

I am using Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 and gradle 8.0

Location in the root:
[image]

Comment: Where did you read that Kotlin DSL required `buildSrc`? And where did you read that Gradle sync would create extra files in `buildSrc`? Both of those assumptions are wrong, and therefore there is nothing strange about what you're seeing. If you want to migrate to Kotlin DSL, rename your `*.gradle` files to `*.gradle.kts`, and then fix the Groovy-specific code to make it Kotlin

Comment: @Joffrey I didn't say it is required, but I know it is used and I would like to use it as well. Tutorial for reference: https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/kotlin-dsl-gradle-scripts-in-android-made-easy-b8e2991e2ba

Comment: This tutorial uses outdated practices, for example sharing dependency versions or coordinates via objects in `buildSrc` (now you should use the versions catalog feature). It also suggests a `buildSrc/src/main/java` folder instead of `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin`. It also insinuates that you need `buildSrc` for Kotlin DSL. Overall the quality is debatable, so I would definitely not follow it to the letter. I suggest you read the doc about Kotlin DSL instead: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html